# Issue in automailing script using Google Apps Script for Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google spreadsheet generated from form's answers and I'm trying to compile automatic mail for form sender, using the script below. However, when I run this, it displayed the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null", eventhough I have filled in the form to insert values in the spreadsheet. Can someone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

```
function emailConfirmation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');

  var recipient = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValue();
  var subject = '[Khóa học viết luận học bổng] Xác nhận đăng ký tham gia';

  var name = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 4).getValue();
  var resno = sheet.getLastRow()
  if (resno <= 5)
  {
  var body = 'Xin chào' + name + ', \r\n Cảm ơn bạn đã đăng ký tham gia Khóa học viết luận học bổng.' + 'Chúc mừng bạn đã trở thành 1 trong 5 người điền đơn đầu tiên.' + 'Phương thức thanh toán cho khóa học là chuyển khoản.';
 
  }
  else
  {
    var body = 'Xin chào' + name + ', \r\n Cảm ơn bạn đã đăng ký tham gia Khóa học viết luận học bổng.' + 'Phương thức thanh toán cho khóa học là chuyển khoản.';
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: How do you run this script? The error indicates that this code:   `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');` cannot get a reference to your sheet, so `sheet = null`

Comment: Perhaps you sheet name is incorrect

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet to verify the issue. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: @Cooper I've just tried to put the sheet name in but it still displayed the same error when i ran the script

Comment: @Sergey can you explain more about what sheet = null means?

Comment: hi @RonM, below is my sheet, i've just run the code to try but it still displayed error so i haven't tried filling the form to see the result https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-_e6bGchJ5rl1HPRjOLCcERr2E-vjl6S1ljyCQrjaY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as what @Sergey and Cooper suspected. You are using an incorrect sheet name in your [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).

Your code should be: `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');`

[image]

- Sheet names are the tab at the bottom part of your Google Sheet file (sample are those encircled with green)

What you used earlier is the Spreadsheet name `Registration Form (Responses)`.

---

What @Sargey means is that, since you provided a sheet name that is not existing in your Google Sheet file when you used `ss.getSheetByName('sheet 1');` or `ss.getSheetByName('Registration Form (Responses)');`, [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) will return `null` since there is no sheet with the given name.

The value [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) represents the intentional absence of any object value.